# WSO2 ESB & ESB Mediator

Tags: jboss, ejb, wso2, wso2-esb

I want to use ESB Mediator of WSO2 ESB 4.5.1, I want to invoke EJBs 3.0, they are deployed in Jboss AS 7.1.1.

Is there any tutorial or sample for ESB Mediator???

Thanks in advance.

---

I have a new error:

```
oreLocatorProxyHttpsSoap11Endpoint, WSAction: urn:mediate, SOAPAction: urn:media
te, MessageID: urn:uuid:ffdefa4b-7cd9-4e53-bcd7-8daf410338ce, Direction: request
[2013-02-25 13:46:36,911] ERROR - ServerWorker Error processing POST request
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
    java:39)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
    sorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
            at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bean.BeanUtils.invokeInstanceMethod(Bean
    Utils.java:74)
            at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bean.enterprise.EJBMediator.mediate(EJBM
    ediator.java:132)
            at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractLis
    tMediator.java:60)
            at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMe
    diator.java:114)
            at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.receive(Pro
    xyServiceMessageReceiver.java:154)
            at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
            at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostReq
    uest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
            at org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosin
    gMethod(ServerWorker.java:416)
            at org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java
    :268)
            at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(Native
    WorkerPool.java:172)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExec
    utor.java:886)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
    .java:908)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Could anybody help me??

Thanks in advance.

---

I have followed the tutorial http://wso2.org/library/articles/2012/06/ejb-mediator-action-wso2-esb-450 with WSO2 ESB 4.5.1 and Jboss 5.0.1.GA, but when I invoke the proxy services I get the next error:

```
  [2013-02-22 13:43:57,682]  INFO - ProxyService Successfully created the Axis2 se
   rvice for Proxy service : StoreLocatorProxy
   [2013-02-22 13:47:41,953] ERROR - NativeWorkerPool Uncaught exception
   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
   java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
   sorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bean.BeanUtils.invokeInstanceMethod(Bean
   Utils.java:74)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bean.BeanMediator.mediateSetPropertyActi
   on(BeanMediator.java:191)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bean.BeanMediator.mediate(BeanMediator.j
   ava:119)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractLis
   tMediator.java:60)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMe
   diator.java:114)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.receive(Pro
   xyServiceMessageReceiver.java:154)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.util.RESTUtil.invokeAxisEngine(RESTUt
   il.java:144)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.util.RESTUtil.processURLRequest(RESTU
   til.java:139)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.util.RESTUtil.processGetAndDeleteR
   equest(RESTUtil.java:140)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.DefaultHttpGetProcessor.processGet
   AndDelete(DefaultHttpGetProcessor.java:464)
        at org.wso2.carbon.transport.nhttp.api.NHttpGetProcessor.process(NHttpGe
   tProcessor.java:296)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java
  :265)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(Native
   WorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExec
   utor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
   .java:908)
```

Could anybody help me??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is useful
http://www.dushantech.com/2012/06/syntaxhighlighter.html

Answer (score 1):

You can refer the OT article"EJB Mediator In Action WSO2 ESB 4.5.0" on [1].

[1]. http://wso2.org/library/articles/2012/06/ejb-mediator-action-wso2-esb-450

Thank You,
Dharshana.